# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS while setting up Ghost + Nginx with both HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: http, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

I'm deploying Ghost (0.7.6) in a VPS using Nginx (1.8.1). To make the dashboard and sign-in page secure, I force any request to use HTTPS when accessing such pages (such as `/ghost` page). But, for any request to any other page (such as accessing the Ghost blog itself) I want to force it to use HTTP. Ghost is up listening on `127.0.0.1:2368`.

Strangely, the result is not as what I expected: Every time I access my blog (let's say the url is `a.b`), it says that my site has `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` and it redirects between `http://a.b` and `https://a.b` (or between `http://a.b/signin` and `https://a.b/signin`). BUT, when I access the admin dashboard (`https://a.b/ghost` or `http://a.b/ghost`), it acts as expected (no error, correctly redirects to use HTTPS).

Any help?

My Nginx configuration:

```
# Configuration for http://a.b
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name a.b;
    location ^~ /ghost { # /ghost should be accessed securely
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    }
}

# Configuration for http://a.b
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name a.b;
    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers '...';

    location ^~ /ghost { # /ghost should be accessed securely
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    }
    location / { # Force to use HTTP
        return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated :')

Comment: Why not simply enable https on the whole website ? It's simpler to maintain, safer for you, faster for you visitors if you use spdy or http2.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/2796

```
location ^~ /ghost { # /ghost should be accessed securely
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
}
```